# Is there a method to find the possible exponents of an integer?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For example,

$16$ is $2^4$ and $4^2$

so the possible exponents are $2$ and $4$.

However, what if the number is larger, say

$634964616$

I'm writing a C program to compute possible exponents.

Thanks.

Comment: There are very few possible exponents — the largest possible one is $\lfloor \log_2(n)\rfloor$ — so you can just search to see whether the number is a square, third power, etc. individually. Each of those is relatively straightforward.

Comment: Factoring is difficult, in general.  Here, of course, you can numerically check small exponents, after which you are down to a very small number of things to test.  Here, for instance, $\sqrt[5] {634964616}<58$ so, having eliminated the powers $≤5$, you only need test numbers up to $57$.

Comment: pari/gp has a command "ispower(n)". If a positive integer is returned (it is then greater than $1$) , every divisor of this number is a possible exponent. This can be done extremely efficient as mentioned, at least for any reasonable input for the number. And yes, factoring would be far too slow.

Comment: However, it *is* useful to check small primes. (What "small" is depends on the number, and some other considerations.) On the one hand, **if** you find a small prime, or better yet several small primes, dividing your number $n$, then determining the exponents of those primes in the factorisation of $n$ restricts the possible exponents drastically. If $p^k \parallel n$, then only divisors of $k$ need to be checked as candidate exponents. If you find several, $p_1^{k_1}, \dotsc, p_r^{k_r}$, only divisors of $\gcd(k_1, \dotsc, k_r)$ need to be checked. And you then compute the $d^{\text{th}}$...

Comment: ...roots of a smaller number ($n\cdot p_1^{-k_1}\cdot \ldots \cdot p_r^{-k_r}$), which is faster. On the other hand, if you don't find a small prime factor, you know at least a larger lower bound for the base, and correspondingly a smaller upper bound for the exponent. In the example of the question, the prime factor $2$ is obvious, one quickly finds the exponent $3$, hence if $634964616$ is a perfect power, it can only be a cube (which it isn't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can see that $64=2^6$ so combinations $2^6, 4^3, 8^2$ are also valid.

For $634964616$ you can divide by $2$ three times before you get an odd number $79370577$ and $\sqrt{79370577}\approx 8909$ so the maximum tests you would have to make are $\frac{8908}{2}=4454$  which is the number of odd numbers $3\le d\le 8989$. In the end you will find

$$634964616 = 2^3×3^3×11×13×61×337$$
In any case, you never have to text more than $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}$ times to get all factors. If you keep track of factor exponents in an array, you can compare which have what numbers of exponents and figure out the "sought" exponents from there.

If you had a number that was a power of just one other, then the routine would be easier still. For instance, dividing $10077696$ by $2$ $9$ times, you get $19683$ and if you divide that by $3$ $9$ times you get the number $1$. So $10077696=6^9=216^3$.

Comment: $4^4 \ne 64$, i guess you mean $4^3$.

Comment: @ jjagmath oops, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be assuming you will have a lot of choices.  You won't.

$634964616$ is divisible by $2^3$ but not by $2^4$.  So $634964616 = 2^3K$ where $K$ is odd.  If $634964616 = a^d$ then then $2^3K =a^d$ which means $2^{\frac 3d}K^{\frac 1d} = a$ is an integer.  But $2^{\frac 3d}$ is only rational if $d|3$ so $d = 1$ or $3$.

So we have $634964616 = 634964616^1$ or $634964616 = (2\sqrt[3]{K})^3$ are the only two options and the second is only an option if $K$ is a perfect cube.  Which it aint.

So you can do this but figuring out the power of $2$ factors, then $3$ and so on.  It will filter down *really* quickly$.